# Ideal method of multiplying mixed fractional number to prevent overflow?

Tags: language-agnostic, math, overflow

I have a simple class that contains three **unsigned** integer fields: a whole value, a numerator, and a denominator, representing a mixed number of the form:

```
<Whole> <Num>/<Den>  // e.g. 3 1/2
```

I'd like to be able to multiply instances of these classes with each other, but since my main app uses relatively large numbers, I'm concerned about overflow. Is there an algorithm for performing this kind of multiplication that minimizes the potential for multiplication overflow?

I'm OK with having overflow if it's unavoidable, what I'm looking for is for a way to "intelligently" multiply to avoid having overflow if it's possible.

Comment: Approaching the max value of an unsigned 64-bit integer (what I'm using in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the least-common-multiple (LCM) of the two denominators can help to keep the numbers small.  There is a lot of info on wikipedia, have a look at the "Reduction by greatest common divisor" section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple and the "Implementations" section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you actually needed info on multiplying mixed numbers... but this site explains how to do it fairly simply: [Multiplying Mixed Numbers](http://www.mathsisfun.com/mixed-fractions-multiply.html).

At any rate... the data structure you've created has inherited the limitations of its parts. That is to say, even if you were just working with rounded up unsigned ints, you were still going to end up with the potential for overflow. If you're worried about blowing out your unsigned int then you should consider bumping the type you're using up to something that can handle larger numbers.

Wikipedia has a pretty good summary on Arithmetic Overflow and some ideas for handling it: [Arithmetic Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way of doing it without resorting to arbitrary presision arithmetics as well. Unless you are coding in assembly, it's more of a curiosity rather than a useful algorithm, but it may be worth mentioning.

```
    int dividend = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int remainder = 0;

    while( num != 0 ) {
        boolean bit = <take the topmost bit of num>
        dividend = remainder << 1;
        if( bit ) {
          dividend += whole;
        }
        int quotient = dividend / div;
        result = (result << 1) + quotient;
        remainder = dividend % div;
        num = num << 1;
    }
    result <<= 1;
    result += ( remainder << 1 ) / div;
```

I know the loop is clumsy but my mind's gone blank and I can't rephrase it so that everything fits neatly into it, but you should get the general idea, which is basically perform the multiplication bit by bit while you're doing the division.

Comment: interesting, but what are the inputs and outputs to your algorithm (num,whole,div, result ?) and how do they map to the problem statement?

Comment: @Jason S Num and whole are what the OP called num and whole, div is the divisor, it should really read `Den`. Result is the result. :)

Comment: OK, I'm missing something then. The OP mentions multiplying two mixed fractions, e.g. (W1 + N1/D1) * (W2 + N2/D2). I don't see that in your code.

Comment: @Jason S Me neither. I thought he wanted to multiply Whole with Num/Den. My only excuse was tiredness and the fact that writing two values after each other means multiplication where I come from.